# References about properties of the induced module/representation from trivial module/representation of a particular subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Let $W$ be the trivial $\mathbb{C}H$-module, and $V=\mathbb{C}G\otimes_{\mathbb{C}H}W$ the induced module, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex field. Then what can we say about $V$ when $H$ is a particular subgroup of $G$, such as abelian, nilpotent or solvable? May someone give me a note or some references about this question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the answer is not much. What kind of thing would you like to be able to say? In general, the representation afforded by $V$ is called a (linear) permutation representation. One standard result is that the permutation action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ is doubly transitive if and only if $V$ decomposes as the trivial module plus an  irreducible module.

Comment: I agree with Derek and expect the answer is "not much". An example from combinatorics occurs when H is an n-cycle and G is the symmetric group on n letters. The irreducible decomposition is known to be determined by the number of standard Young tableaux of size n with major index congruent to 0 mod n. This is rather intricate.